# Using Webpack for hot-loader and generating a physical file w/ ReactJs ES6

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack

I have a ReactJs ES6 (ie 'import' keywords) app that uses gulp for generating a physical build file and webpack for hot-loading the changes to a virtual file. I wanted to combine the two services with npm start (which current loads webpack, not gulp).

**server.js file**

```
 var webpack = require('webpack');
 var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
 var config = require('./webpack.config');

 new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
   publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
   hot: true,
   historyApiFallback: true
 }).listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err);
   }

   console.log('Listening at localhost:3000');
 });
```

---

**webpack.config.js file**

```
 var path = require('path');
 var webpack = require('webpack');

 module.exports = {
   devtool: 'eval',
   entry: [
     'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
     'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
     './src/index.js'
   ],
   output: {
       filename: 'bundle.js',
       path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
       publicPath: '/static/'
   },

   plugins: [
     new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
     new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
   ],
   resolve: {
     extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
   },
   module: {
     loaders: [{
       test: /\.jsx?$/,
       loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel-loader'],
       include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
       exclude: /node_modules/
     },
       { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader' }
     ]
   }
 };
```

I thought based on webpack's output section, webpack would generate a physical file in my build folder while creating a virtual file in '/static/bundle.js'

Currently, the virtual file with hot-loader is working, but no physical file has been built in the 'build' path.

Am I correct that webpack can replace gulp and generate both a physical & virtual build file? If so, where is my code in err as far as creating a physical build file?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

My code is fine, I needed to add to my scripts in package.json:

```
 .....
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"build": "webpack",
"gulp": "gulp",
"all":  "npm run build && npm run gulp"
 .....
```

I then run "npm run all" and I can run webpack and gulp from one command